# Get the last inserted id using just MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to be able to get the last inserted id in a mysql table using just mysql.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO groups (name, customer_id)
SELECT
groups.name as name,
'2' as customer_id
FROM products
LEFT JOIN groups ON products.group_id=groups.id
WHERE customer_id=1;
```

Now that I have selected a group from one user and created a new group with the same name for another user, I would like to update all products to have the new group id instead of the old one.

```
UPDATE products SET
group_id=...last inserted id...
WHERE customer_id=2;
```

Is this possible using just mysql?

Comment: Better wrap all that inside a transaction

Comment: @ringø Can you explain that a little more. I need to do alot of these actions. If there are methods to make it easier, i would very much like to know them.

Comment: I believe what he is trying to say is to use `START TRANSACTION;` in the beginning of your insert/update statements and end with `COMMIT;`

Comment: @PierreDuc What would be the use?

Comment: This prevents the odd case when there happens to be another `INSERT` from another session in between the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements. And thus generating a wrong `LAST_INSERT_ID`. I will update my answer to implement this. The other use is that if something went wrong in either the `UPDATE` or `INSERT`, both are rolled back

Comment: @PierreDuc ["The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) -- so if another session inserts in between the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, it doesn't matter; it won't affect the value that's returned to your session. Obviously a transaction is still a good idea, to make sure that if the `products` update fails, the `groups` insert rolls back, but you'll always get the right ID, with or without a transaction.

Comment: @MattGibson Oh no. I've been taught wrong years ago. Thank you for this update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

```
UPDATE products SET
group_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHERE customer_id=2;
```

That should work..

You should use a transaction to prevent an `INSERT` if the `UPDATE` went wrong and the other way around. This helps the integrity of your data

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO groups (name, customer_id)
   SELECT
     groups.name as name,
     '2' as customer_id
   FROM products
   LEFT JOIN groups ON products.group_id=groups.id
   WHERE customer_id=1;

UPDATE products SET
group_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHERE customer_id=2;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow it was hard to find this. All I got was PHP related methods when I googled it.